# How to add one mvc3 c# project into other executable project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have  mvc3 project when I start debugging it show messbox like this

[image]

How can i put this project into another executable project?Any idea?

Comment: is your start up project option pointed at your web project?

Comment: You can set the startup project to you webapplication

Comment: I put forum mvc project into standard mvc project.Then i select startup project in which project?forum or standard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there are multiple projects in the solution and start up project needs setting.

The MVC projects which you created needs to be the start up project.

To set a single startup project (VS 2010 and 2012)
1.In Solution Explorer, select the desired startup project within your solution.
2.On the Project menu, choose Set as StartUp Project.

Source:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1awth7y(v=vs.80).aspx

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

just go to the properties of the project then in the output tab change the output type from class library into executable .
after did this run your project.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Daniel: Click right on your MVC3 project, and select "Set as StartUp Project".